# Create File in External SD Card

Tags: android, file, storage, android-sdcard, sd-card

I'm new in android developing.
I want create a File in my external SD Card. I searched a lot and tried different codes. But it created in device storage or it doesn't create at all.
I get my SD Card path, it was in /mnt/extSdCard.
I even tried several code, but non of them doesn't work.
this code found my SD Card location:

```
 public static String getExternalSdCardPath() {
    String path = null;

    File sdCardFile = null;
    List<String> sdCardPossiblePath = Arrays.asList("external_sd", "ext_sd", "external", "extSdCard");

    for (String sdPath : sdCardPossiblePath) {
        File file = new File("/mnt/", sdPath);

        if (file.isDirectory() && file.canWrite()) {
            path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.i("LOG", "path is: " + path);

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            File testWritable = new File(path, "test_" + timeStamp);
            if (testWritable.mkdirs()) {
                testWritable.delete();
            } else {
                path = null;
            }
        }
    }

    if (path != null) {
        sdCardFile = new File(path);
    } else {
        sdCardFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return sdCardFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

path is my location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35947286/115145

Comment: Do you check and request permissions? take a loot at [saving files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: yes, of course. it is WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Dev: Accessing external SD card directly on Samsung devices (with extSdCard path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947286/android-dev-accessing-external-sd-card-directly-on-samsung-devices-with-extsdc)

Comment: it create in device storage but it's not successfully to write in extSdCard. it doesn't work for me @ValiaSergeev

Comment: @Amirkenarang, do you have a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest? And, do you ask run time permission on Android 6+?

Comment: @ValiaSergeev , yes I did it, it doesn't work. it just write on Phone Storage not External storage.

Comment: @Amirkenarang see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you use the code to set your path to the SD CARD if you do not have a SD CARD Android will just store data in INTERNAL STORAGE 
First declare this variable on the launch Activity

```
public static String THE_PATH;
```

Then in the same Activity in the onCreate Bundle call this method onAvail()

```
    // Is External Storage Available if so use it and desi the path for DBHelper
public void onAvail() {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) &&
```

(!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))) {

```
        File removable = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];
        THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable);
        //System.out.println("EXTERNAL PATH ====> " + THE_PATH);
        THE_PATH = THE_PATH + "/Documents/";
        //System.out.println("new path ====> "+THE_PATH);
    }
}
```

I hope you have a DBHelper Class here is what happens in that Class

```
import static <app name here>.MainActivity.THE_PATH;

 // Variable str is set in MainActivity as Public static
// to be accessible in the DBHelper Class
```

// which is called from MainAvtivity

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DB_NAME = THE_PATH +"PassWord";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs()` to get array of available string paths, including one which you want. But, it only available in Android 4.4+.